# Import dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlimport

I want to import a csv file into a database

**Header**
id,name,surname,date1,date2

**Data**
10001,Bob,Roberts,03/06/2007 15:18:25.10,03/06/2007 15:18:29.19

This file has millions of rows and in order to import it I used the following command:

```
mysqlimport  --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --columns='id,name,surname,date1,date2' --local -u root -p Database /home/server/Desktop/data.csv
```

My problem is that when I try to import the file dates are not stored properly and they look like this:

```
'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

I tried many things but nothing works. I suppose the problem is given by the fact that the time has milliseconds and there is a dot rather than a colon at the end of the string.

My dates are stored in a timestamp variable

Can you help me please

Thanks

Comment: The datetime format for MySql looks more like "2014-09-01 00:00:00",  Is there a way you can convert the string from the CSV to match that on the way in?

Comment: If you load it on excel you can easily change the date format to one accepted by MySQL and reexport to a CSV again once you're done.

Comment: How can I open in excel a 20 million rows dataset?

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino I haven't found a formal way to convert date format while using mysqlimport. I updated my answer suggesting the use of the LOAD DATA command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played with this issue for a bit and I solved it converting my dates with an awk script and upgrading mysql to version 5.6 which supports milliseconds

Thanks anyway

Comment: Cool. Now, if you mark yours or another answer as the accepted one your are going to make this post more relevant :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your dates aren't in the MySql standard format, which is "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS".

Mysqlimport should be able to accept some date conversion function among the command line parameters, like you would do if you were using "LOAD DATA" command (which is used by mysqlimport utility), but at this time it isn't:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55666

Here's some way to workaround this:

http://blog.dgaspar.com/2010/08/01/the-set-clause/

If you want to do this conversion at one step and don't want to use that workaround, you will need to directly use "LOAD DATA" command:

```
load data infile '/tmp/xxx.dat' 
into table xxx 
fields terminated by '|' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
(col1, 
col2, 
@col3, 
@col4, 
col5) 
set 
col3 = str_to_date(@col3, '%m/%d/%Y'), 
col4 = str_to_date(@col4, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

I got this code from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html#c8828

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you import the data into a staging table, where all the columns are strings (say `varchar(255)`.  Then do the type conversion in MySQL to the final form.  This will make it much easier to debug the code and to figure out the exact conversion you need.

You will be able to use `str_to_date()` to do the conversion.